# droid x bluetooth volume too low

Tags: bluetooth, motorola-droid-x

Does anyone know how I can get under the hood and modify the db output for my bluetooth media levels? I've read numerous posts of people complaining about this problem but am unable to find a solution.  On previous phones, I was able to access the underlying system settings by inputting some lengthy combination of numbers.  I don't know if this sort of hardware access exists on the droid x. I'm not finding anything on-line as to how to do this.
All ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

## Configurations

For most devices, you can only modify the volume of the earpiece, bluetooth, media volume or call volume if you are currently using that feature.

So, the best is to use your device "menu" button when you are using the bluetooth earpiece and check if said option exists. Alternativly, use the volume up/down from your device while with the bluetooth earpiece in use to try and control its volume.

One user at [droidxforums](http://www.droidxforums.com/forum/droid-x-help/24714-voice-prompt-bluetooth-volume-too-low.html#post361101) mentioned a working solution for him:

> Turn off the Bluetooth on the Droid X. Place a phone call like normal. Adjust the call volume to the MAX and then hang up. Turn the Bluetooth on the Droid X back on and activate your voice command. It will work. You can adjust volume up or down in that fashion.

---

## Apps

If to no avail, currently, there are a few apps available from Google Play Store to deal with issues like this:

### Recommended for custom ROM:

[Volume+ FREE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.FREE.android.lvh) and the donate version [Volume+ (Volume Boost)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TEST.android.lvh)

Gives great results in controlling volume settings separably for each sound output available.

[image: Volume+ Screenshot]

### Recommended for Stock ROM

[Bluetooth Volume](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nightshadelabs.bluetoothvolume)

Worked as promised to control the bluetooth sound output, ideal for boosting in call volume.

[image: Bluetooth Volume Screenshot]

<sup>This are the ones I have used with excellent results, you can find others at Google Play Store.</sup>