# How can I boost the mic level of my Bluetooth headset?

Tags: bluetooth, calls

When I make calls with my Bluetooth headset, often the person on the other end of the line complains that I am too quiet and it's difficult to hear me. How can I boost the level of my Bluetooth headset so I sound louder to others? (I looked at [droid x bluetooth volume too low](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10058/droid-x-bluetooth-volume-too-low) but that is the opposite of what I want: I don't want the headset's output louder, I want the input from the headset louder.)